# Should I use request.GET['...'] or form.cleaned_data.get('...')

Tags: django

I have created a function for a search form form my database, method works fine, but I, don't know whether I should use `queryBooks = request.GET['queryBooks']` or `form.cleaned_data.get('queryBooks')`

Here is my code.

```
# views.py
def SearchBook(request):
    error = False
    message = ''
    books = Books.objects.all()

    if 'queryBooks' in request.GET:     
        queryBooks = request.GET['queryBooks']
        if not queryBooks:          
            error = True
            message = u'enter book or author title'         
        else:
            books = Books.objects.filter\
            (
                Q(book__icontains=queryBooks) | Q(Author__name__icontains=queryBooks)
            )
    contexto = {'Books': books, 'Error': error, 'Message': message}
    return render(request, 'list_of_book.html', contexto)


# list_of_book.html
        <form action="" method="get">        
            <input type="text" name="queryBooks">
            <input type="submit" value="search">
        </form>  

# urls.py
url(r'^books/search/$', SearchBook, name='searchBook'),
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `form` in your view, so

```
form.cleaned_data.get('queryBooks')
```

Would give you an error.

In general, I recommend that you learn about [Django forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/), as they take care of rendering the html, and validating the input from the user. For your specific example, fetching the query string from `request.GET` is probably ok.